# wrap ctrl + enter in str() function r

Tags: r, rstudio

I often find myself using `ctrl + enter` to run something in r-studio. I often find that I would like to be able to wrap whatever I am putting into `ctrl + enter` in the `str()` function.

This is particularly the case when I am piping lots of dplyr verbs together. Mutating new variables and joining dataframes etc. Sometimes halfway through the set of piped commands I need to check what the name of a variable in a dataframe that i have created is called so that i can access it via the next pipe. This usually means that i have to:

1. highlight the text up to the last relevant pipe
2. hit `ctrl + enter`
3. press the up arrow
4. add a bracket to the end of the pasted text
5. Press home
6. navigate via the arrows to the first line of the pasted text
7. type: `str(`

This is extremely laborious and I find myself doing it often. Is there a shorter way that I am not aware of? Otherwise is there a workflow process people use to get around this?

Ideally there would be a modified `ctrl + enter` shortcut that would wrap whatever is highlighted in `str()` and output the result to the terminal.

Comment: You could probably write a fairly simple [RStudio addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/#overview) to do this, you can assign keyboard shortcuts to the actions in an addin.

Comment: If you're using pipes load `magrittr` and add `%T>% str %>%` in your pipeline. Or maybe it's an indication you shouldn't make your pipelines *quite* so long...

Comment: In the meantime `.Last.value` (being the last thing executed) is quite handy.